# Número e tamanho máximo de cookies

Tags: cookies, navegador-de-internet

Ao investigar sobre cookies e as suas limitações, deparei-me com esta página da Microsoft onde falam sobre o Internet Explorer e as suas capacidades relativamente a Cookies:

[Limites de tamanho e números de um cookie no Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070/pt-br)

> Microsoft Internet Explorer está em conformidade com as seguintes RFC 2109 recomendado mínimas limitações:
>
> - pelo menos 300 cookies
> - pelo menos 4096 bytes por cookie (como medido pelo tamanho dos caracteres que compõem o terminal na descrição da sintaxe do cabeçalho Set-Cookie cookie)
> - pelo menos 20 cookies por nome de host ou domínio exclusivo

Também vi as normas:

- [RFC2109 de Fev-1997](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), mais especificamente a secção *6.3  Implementation Limits* <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [RFC2965 de Out-2000](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) mais especificamente a secção *5.3  Implementation Limits* <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

que estabelecem o comportamento base para estandardizar a utilização e disponibilização de cookies nos diversos navegadores disponíveis, onde de forma resumida falam que navegadores *limitados* devem no mínimo disponibilizar aquilo que já vinha mencionado no artigo em cima citado.

Contudo, não fiquei esclarecido o suficiente sobre um *número aceitável* de cookies que vá funcionar em todos os [navegadores mais utilizados](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, bem como o tamanho máximo que cada cookie poderá conter de forma a garantir que não vão existir perdas de dados na aplicação.

Ficou a dúvida sobre os navegadores mais utilizados (IE, FF, Chrome e Safari), se os mesmos se estarão a reger pelos mínimos em cima mencionados, ou de facto temos uma margem de manobra um pouco maior para a utilização dos cookies provenientes do mesmo domínio.

De igual forma, quando se referem a *domínio* nas normas apresentadas, estão a dizer que www.site.com é diferente de app.site.com, ou os limites terão que ser partilhados por ambos?

## Pergunta

Assumindo um cenário do género:

- `www.mysite.com` Web-site institucional
- `app.mysite.com` Aplicação para desktop
- `m.mySite.com` Versão *mobile* do web-site institucional
- `cdn.mysite.com` CDN a servir imagens e recursos partilhados para os listados em cima

Com o que é que se pode contar a nível de número de cookies e o seu valor em bytes de forma a garantir que no seu conjunto a solução para o `*.mySite.com` vai funcionar?

Comment: Meu Chrome suporta aproximadamente 120 cookies. Percebi isso há alguns dias após acessar um site onde, para cada página acessada, um cookie era definido. Após um certo tempo, não conseguir mais acessar o site. Após limpar alguns cookies, consegui acessar até que o limite fosse novamente alcançado.

Answer (score 5):

Segundo [Internet Explorer Cookie Internals](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219133530/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx) da Microsoft, tanto Internet Explorer como Firefox possuem limite de 50 cookies por domínio sendo que:

- cada cookie não pode ter mais de 5kb;
- document.cookie tem limite próprio de apenas 10kb;

**Respondendo sua pergunta:**

> Com o que é que se pode contar a nível de número de cookies e o seu
> valor em bytes de forma a garantir que no seu conjunto a solução para
> o *.mySite.com vai funcionar?

Você pode contar com até 50 cookies e no máximo 250kb de dados por request por site.

Meu conselho é que você esqueça cookies e passe a usar localStorage. Basicamente é suportado em todas as versões modernas de navegadores (IE desde a versão 8, safari versão 4) e suporta [grandes quantidades de dados](https://arty.name/localstorage.html).

Comment: Ia perguntar isso, mas está muito bem esclarecido. +1