# Usar Cookies ou Banco de Dados?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, cookies

Preciso criar um carrinho onde armazene mais de um dado
Exemplo:
`ID_PRODUTO`, `ID_VENDEDOR`

Gostaria de utilizar Cookies pro sistema ficar mais leve, porém encontrei um grande problema, o Cookie armazena os dados em 1 linha:

> COOKIE VALUE =
>   ID_PRODUTO=1&ID_VENDEDOR=2&&ID_PRODUTO=111&ID_VENDEDOR=222&&ID_PRODUTO=999&ID_VENDEDOR=777

Fica complicado pra verificar se já possui o produto no carrinho. Algum sugestão sobre como decidir pelo Cookie ou Banco de Dados?

Comment: O maior problema é o limite de tamanho dos cookies. Se precisar guardar muitos dados, pode não caber. Portanto o volume de dados é crucial para decidir usar um bd ou não. Se decidir ficar com os cookies, vai precisar de chaves mais complexas, ou não saberá qual produto está vinculado a qual vendedor (eu não confiaria na ordem).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>O título da tua pergunta refere-se à decisão de optar por utilizar Cookies ou uma base-de-dados para armazenar informação. O conteúdo da tua pergunta apresenta um problema sobre a maneira como a informação é guardada num Cookie e questiona sobre um método eficaz de lidar com a mesma. Vou tentar responder a ambas as questões.</sup>

## Cookie *vs* Base de Dados

Conforme já mencionado no [comentário do @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9443/usar-cookies-ou-banco-de-dados#comment16062_9443), a densidade da informação é o maior ponto de decisão no que respeita à utilização de Cookies ou utilização de uma base-de-dados para guardar informação, mesmo que temporária.

Para te ajudar a decidir, podes analisar esta pergunta onde se tenta entender os limites dos Cookies e a viabilidade dos mesmos:

#### [Número e tamanho máximo de cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2476/223)

No final, só tu podes *responder* se Cookies são a melhor opção quando comparados com uma base-de-dados no que respeita ao trabalho que estás a desenvolver.

Pessoalmente, utilizaria base-de-dados ou *localStorage* uma vez que ficamos com o trabalho preparado para um crescimento substancial no que respeita ao número de produtos no carrinho.

## Informação *organizada* num Cookie

De forma a conseguires organizar a informação que vai ser armazenada no Cookie numa forma a que faça sentido, tenha alguma leitura e possa ser trabalhada com alguma eficácia, recomendo o uso da função [JSON.stringify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que te permite serializar um valor:

> Serializes a JavaScript value into JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) text

Que traduzido:

> Serializa um valor JavaScript num JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) texto

#### Exemplo prático

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/83qCn/)

```js
// criamos um objecto
var meuDados = new Object();

// Criamos um sub-objecto para o nosso primeiro produto
meuDados.Produto1 = new Object();
meuDados.Produto1.ID_PRODUTO  = '1';
meuDados.Produto1.ID_VENDEDOR = '2';


// Criamos um sub-objecto para o nosso segundo produto
meuDados.Produto2 = new Object();
meuDados.Produto2.ID_PRODUTO  = '111';
meuDados.Produto2.ID_VENDEDOR = '222';

// etc...
```

Desta forma temos a informação organizada num objecto multi-dimensional que podemos converter num JSON para armazenar no Cookie:

```js
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(meuDados);
```

E o resultado final do texto a guardar no Cookie é:

```js
// linha de texto
{"Produto1":{"ID_PRODUTO":"1","ID_VENDEDOR":"2"},"Produto2":{"ID_PRODUTO":"111","ID_VENDEDOR":"222"}}

// visão estruturada da linha de texto
{
  "Produto1" : {
      "ID_PRODUTO"  : "1",
      "ID_VENDEDOR" : "2"
  },
  "Produto2": {
      "ID_PRODUTO"  : "111",
      "ID_VENDEDOR" : "222"
  }
}
```

Com a informação organizada perdemos algum espaço devido ao caracteres que efectivamente denotam a estrutura dos dados, mas o trabalho de processar a informação fica simplificado.

Já vimos como escrever os dados, vamos agora ver como os podemos recolher e interpretar onde para o efeito podemos utilizar a função [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que nos permite transformar o texto com a denotação correcta num objecto:

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

Que traduzido:

> O método JSON.parse() analisa uma string como JSON, opcionalmente, transformando o valor produzido pela análise.

```js
// Ler o JSON de texto para um objecto como tínhamos antes
var meusDados = JSON.parse(jsonText);

// Função para procurar o produto
function procuraProduto(objecto, id) {
    for (var x in objecto) {
        for (var y in objecto[x]) {
            if (y=="ID_PRODUTO" && objecto[x][y]==id) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Procuramos um produto em particular pelo ID
if (procuraProduto(meusDados, "111")) {
    alert("Yap, está cá!");
} else {
    alert("Ora bolas, não está!");
}
```

Comment: Se precisar de um formato menor poderia usar algo como `...&ID_VENDEDOR=ID_PRODUTO`, por exemplo, `1=15&1=21&2=13`. Para fazer o parse, basta dividir a string por `&` e depois por `=`