# Qual a quantidade de dados os cookies podem armazenar?

Tags: aplicação-web, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, internet-explorer

Cookies são informações armazenadas por sites em seu computador mas qual a quantidade de dados os cookies podem armazenar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível resposta em [Número e tamanho máximo de cookies](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2476/n%c3%bamero-e-tamanho-m%c3%a1ximo-de-cookies)

Comment: Sim...acebei vendo isso depois devido ao titulo estar diferente, mas se trata da mesma pergunda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

achei isto em [How Many Cookies Can You Use on One Website](https://www.thoughtco.com/cookie-limit-per-domain-3466809) Updated October 09, 2016

1. O Chrome não tem limite nos bytes máximos por domínio
2. O Firefox não tem limite nos bytes máximos por domínio
3. Internet Explorer permite entre 4096 e 10234 bytes
4. Opera permite 4096 bytes
5. Safari permite 4096 bytes

> LIMITES DE TAMANHO DO COOKIE QUE VOCÊ DEVE SEGUIR
>   Para ser compatível com a maioria dos navegadores, você não deve criar mais de 30 cookies por domínio e todos os 30 cookies não devem ocupar mais de 4 KB de espaço (4096 bytes).

Se você pretende extrapolar esses limites use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (HTML5 - armazenamento local). Com o localStorage  o limite de armazenamento é muito maior (pelo menos 5 MB).