# Armazenar array dentro de Cookie

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.6

É possível armazenar um *array* dentro de um *Cookie*?

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
$carrinho = array(array('frete' => '', 'mercados' => array()));

Cookie::queue('carrinho', $carrinho, 525600);
```

Mas me retorna o erro:

> Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie::__construct() must be of the
>   type string or null, array given, called in
>   /var/www/html/seusuper/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.php

Esse mesmo *array* funciona normal se eu tento armazenar em uma *session*.

Estou utilizando o *Laravel* 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é mais fácil usar o `session`?

```
session(array('frete' => '', 'mercados' => array()));
```

Eu creio até que seja o mais indicado para a situação, já que o Cookie possui algumas limitações em relação aos dados que você pode colocar nele, principalmente em [relação ao tamanho dos dados armazenados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2476/n%C3%BAmero-e-tamanho-m%C3%A1ximo-de-cookies).

Comment: Vou continuar utilizando session mesmo. Não tava ligado nessa relação de tamanhos armazenados em cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Uma das formas para resolveres o problema seria serializar o array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Com o valor como string já poderias colocar no cookie.

Comment: O problema é que o cookie vai ficar assim: a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"frete";s:0:"";s:8:"mercados";a:0:{}}}. Aí fica inviável para  percorrer o cookie e manipular os valores depois.

Comment: @DiegoVieira podes unserialize em Javascript